# router is undefined in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router

I create done vue js app. In which i have main index.js file for routes and i made different route file for other view and all my child file extend in main index.js route file.

**index.js (Main route file)**
Below I import my child routes in this file

import test1 from './test1'
import test from './test'

My child route file test1

```
export default [{
  path: '/roles',
  component: Layout2,
  children: [{
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('@/views/test/test1'),
    meta: {
        auth: true
    },
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if(checkPermission("readUser")){
        router.push({
                name: 'unauthorized'
            })
        }
    }
  }
  }]
}]
```

Now issue is i am trying push `unauthorized` in url by using before route, but it gives me error like router is not defined. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: yes it's in my base route file

Comment: It doesn't work like that. If you use any variable, function, etc in a file, it needs to be imported to the same file. See my answer. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should creater router instance first, and export it.

```
export const router = new VueRouter(routes)

const routes = {
   path: '/roles',
   component: Layout2,
   ... etc.
}
```

Then import router into main js file.